Speeding up zero-shot headline categorization with BART on Huggingface
I’m working on a Flask web app that needs to categorize 300 headlines into 9-16 dynamic categories every hour very quickly. I'm using the Facebook BART model via Huggingface's API. My current implementation in Python takes 3-5 seconds per headline, which is too slow. Ideally I'd like to do the whole list in 3-5 seconds. Is that possible?
def categorise(categories, item):
    API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/facebook/bart-large-mnli"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"}
    payload = {
        "inputs": item,
        "parameters": {"candidate_labels": categories},
    }
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        results = response.json()
        return {"category": results[0]['labels'][0], "confidence": results[0]['scores'][0]}
    else:
        return {"error": f"API request failed with status {response.status_code}"}

I iterate through each headline in a for loop and call this function. Is a way to speed this up much much faster?
I tried using the Huggingface API as I thought BART would be an advanced rapid way to handle categorisation - but it is quite slow.

BART is decently fast, in this case you are probably being limited by the huggingface API rather than the model itself. You would probably see much better results if you have the capacity to host the model yourself and run your queries on it
